# HTTP byte range yields a corrupt audio file?

Tags: file, google-chrome, http, curl, audio

when i open a .m4a or .mp3 file using chrome (or in VLC "open new stream), and skip to a certain time mark, it starts streaming the audio right at that time mark, which means that it downloads a chunk from the audio file starting at that position.

when i check network under chrome dev tools after i click somewhere in the audio player, and copy the cURL request, it contains a range http header, for example:

```
-H "Range: bytes=26500000-30000000"
```

when i run that cURL command in the terminal, the output is a corrupt audio file. if i try to convert it using ffmpeg, it logs:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000164d5a3ab40] moov atom not found
```

the only exception is when i request a byte range starting from 0 (and ending at 300000+) in which case the output file can play.

from what i understand, the headers of the audio file are not downloaded when the byte range is somewhere in the middle or ending of the file.

i tried specifying two ranges, as follows

```
-H "Range: bytes=0-300000,2000000-4000000"
```

but the output file is corrupt nevertheless.

how does chrome/vlc deal with this situation, and how can i replicate it? what is the right way to download an audio chunk from a large audio file? i am guessing i would have to make consecutive http requests to build a proper, non-corrupt file, it seems that it is what chrome does.

***UPDATE***

a "temporary fix" i found to the problem that you might find useful is to use launch VLC through command with a hidden interface, load the audio stream (in this case the audio file url) and transcode the audio to a local file while assigning a start and stop time. an example, with a random podcast:

```
vlc -Idummy --play-and-exit --sout "#transcode{acodec=s16l,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst=C:\audio\output.wav}" --start-time=600 --stop-time=630  "http://traffic.libsyn.com/preview/worldofhardwarestartups/World_of_Hardware_Startups_Podcast_EP01_-_AIR_Ready.mp3"
```

however, the original issue is still unsolved.

Comment: Why do you think that downloading parts of an audio file yield a valid audio file?

Comment: i had a vision about it in my dream thats why